# Reading multiple Excel files in a directory and appending to a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, file, dataframe

All files are located in a directory:

`C:/BD/KENYA/<file name>.xlsx`

All files have the following name format:

`'Kenya 1686 dated 20.03.19'`

So there are two parameters that change:

`1686` (ID number) and `20.03.19` (date)

Pandas does read the full path quite well:

`pd.read_excel('C:/BD/KENYA/Kenya 1686 dated 20.03.19.xlsx')`

But how do i loop through the set of files (around 1900 items) reading data from them and summing all into a Dataframe?

I tried putting the path into a variable:

`path = 'C:/BD/KENYA/Kenya 1686 dated 20.03.19.xlsx'`

This also works. But I fail to concatenate the pieces of the file path.

`os.abspath` - doesn't work.

```
path = 'C:/BD/KENYA/Kenya 1686 dated 20.03.19.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(path)
```

As a result, I need a DataFrame built from multiple Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

```
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

path = 'C:/BD/KENYA/'
files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, 'Kenya * dated *')
df_all = None
for file in files:
  df = pd.read_excel(file)
  if not df_all:
    df_all = df
  else:
    df = df.append(df)
df_all.to_excel('C:/BD/KENYA/Kenya 1686 dated 20.03.19.xlsx')
```